# Simple question on a sub group $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, solution-verification

#### Question:

Let $d$ a divisor of $ n$ and $ n,d \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $ G $ the only sub group with cardinal $ d $ of $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. I want to understand how does looks like the following quotient group $ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G$  and $ \mathbb{Z}/(n/d) \mathbb{Z} $.

*Rem:* I am studying alone some algebra so I have sometimes diffuclties to undersand basic notions.

#### My answer:

*1- Understanding $G$.*
We know that in a cyclic group, every subgroup is also cyclic. If $G$ is a sub group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with cardinality $d$ then by definition of a cyclic group it is generated by only one element.
More over by [Lagrange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)=) for group we know that that $card(G)$ divides $card( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} )$ thus $d$ divides $n$.

Since $d$ divides $n$, there exists an integer $k$ such that $n=dk$. The element that generates $G$ is then $[k]$, as $[k]^d = [k]+[k]+.."d"times ..+[k] = d[k]=[kd] = [n] = [0]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
But as $k=\frac{n}{d}$ has the property that $d$ multiples of $[k]$ will cycle back to $[0]$, the identity element. In other words the subgroup $G$, with cardinality $d$, is generated by the element $[k] = [\frac{n}{d}]$.
This means that $G = \left \{ [0]; [k]; [2k];...;[(d-1)k] \right \} = \left \{ [0]; [n/d]; [2n/d];...;[(d-1)n/d] \right \}$

Exemple: With $n=8, d=4$ we have $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}= \left \{  [0];[1];[2];[3];[4];[5];[6];[7] \right \}$ and $G=\left \{  [0],[2],[4],[6] \right \}$

*2- Understanding $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G$.*
By definition $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G$ is the set of all the left coset of the form $ a+G , a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} $
More over by definition if $a \in G$ all ready so we will have: $a+G=G$. More directly by Lagrange's theorem as $G$ is here a normal sub group of $ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) $ it cames that $card( (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G ) = n/d$

Exemple: With $n=8, d=4$  we have $0+G=G$ , $ 1+G= \left \{  [1],[3],[5],[7] \right \}$. Hence: $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}) / G= \left \{  G; G+1 \right \}$

*3- Understanding $\mathbb{Z}/(n/d) \mathbb{Z} $.*
Directly we get $\mathbb{Z}/(n/d) \mathbb{Z} = \left \{ [0];[1];...;[\frac{n}{d} -1]  \right \}$

Exemple: With $n=8, d=4$ we get $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}=\left \{ [0];[1]  \right \}$

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems that my understanding of this concept as I ve discribded in my question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. In general, let $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ be the cylic group of order $n$ generated by $a$ multiplicatively, and set $1$ as the identity element (for me it is easier to write the elements of the group multiplicatively). Recall that it means that
$$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\{1,a,a^2,\dots,a^{n-2},a^{n-1}\}.$$
Given a subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of order $d$, we can assure that $G$ is going to be generated by $a^{\frac{n}{d}}$. Indeed, notice that, since $d|n$, $\frac{n}{d}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a^{\frac{n}{d}}$ has order $d$.

Now, if we consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G$, which is totally well defined, since we are dealing with abelian groups, we see that the representatives of the cosets are
$$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G=\left\{[1],[a],[a^2],\dots,\left[a^{\frac{n}{d}-1}\right]\right\}.$$
This came from the fact that $g\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is in $[1]$ if and only if $g\in G$, si $g=a^{\frac{kn}{d}}$ for some $0\leq k<d$. That implies that $a\not\in[1]$, and therefore it defined a coset class. Now, $g\in[a]$ if and only if $g=a^{\frac{kn}{d}+1}$ for some $0\leq k<d$. Again, we notice that $a^2\not\in[1]$ and $a^2\not\in[a]$, so it defines another coset class. If we proceed that way we achieve the previous result.

Now we are focusing in $\mathbb{Z}/\left(\frac{n}{d}\mathbb{Z}\right)$. Let $b$ be the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ written multiplicatively as before. Therefore, $\frac{n}{d}\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $b^{\frac{n}{d}}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Proceeding as before, it is easy to check that
$$\mathbb{Z}/\left(\frac{n}{d}\mathbb{Z}\right)=\left\{[1],[b],\dots,\left[b^{\frac{n}{d}-1}\right]\right\}.$$

Therefore, we see that
$$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G\cong\mathbb{Z}/\left(\frac{n}{d}\mathbb{Z}\right),$$
and the isomorphism is clear. We defined the group moprhism $\varphi:(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/\left(\frac{n}{d}\mathbb{Z}\right)$ as $\varphi([a])=[b]$. By the previous results, that is an isomorphism.

As a curiosity, I highly recomend you to prove a slightly more general results:

**Proposition:** *Let $G$ be a cylic group (not necessarily finite), and let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then that $G/N$ is cylic.*

**Proposition:** *Let $G$ and $H$ be two finite cylic groups of the same order. Then that $G\cong N$.*

The combination of this two propositions solve your question. If you have any trouble in case of trying to prove the previous propositions or you do not understand my answer, do not hesitate to ask me!