# Prove that $ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G$ is isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}/ (n/d) \mathbb{Z}$ with $G$ a sub group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

#### Question:

Let $d$ a divisor of $n$ ($n,d \in \mathbb{N}$) and let $G$ the only sub group with cardinal $d$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/ (n/d) \mathbb{Z}$.

-To get a better understanding of how looks like all this sub group you can look here [Simple question on a sub group $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834543/simple-question-on-a-sub-group-g-of-mathbbz-n-mathbbz) (basically I needed to understand this in order solve this question :-) )

#### My answer:

As $G$ is a normal sub group of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ (trivial) we have by the Lagrange's theorem that $card (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G) = \frac{card( (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}))}{card(G)}= \frac{n}{d}$. More over we have too $card(\mathbb{Z}/ (n/d) \mathbb{Z})=\frac{n}{d}$.
So $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G)$ and $ \mathbb{Z}/ (n/d) \mathbb{Z}$ have the same finite number of elements.
Now by recursion it is easy to construct a bijection between $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/ (n/d) \mathbb{Z}$ but I have a problem in order to find a bijectio nthat will be a morphism too (in order to get the asked isomorphism).

Any help (details answer) will be appreciated. Even a lot of different morphism if you succeed to find more than one
Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the isomorphism theorems?

Comment: @MatteoIaccarino thk for your answer. Which isomorphism are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that my answer is correct.

In order to answer this question, we are going to build a such isomorphism.

1-
As I explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834543/simple-question-on-a-sub-group-g-of-mathbbz-n-mathbbz) all the elements in $ (\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} ) / G$ are of the form $a + G$ with $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ (that means $ 0 \leq a \in  \mathbb{N} \leq n-1$ ).
Now let define $f(a+G)= [a]_{\frac{n}{d}} $ with $[a]_{\frac{n}{d}}$ the equivalent class of $a$ in $ \mathbb{Z}/(n/d) \mathbb{Z}$. That means that $[a]_{\frac{n}{d}}$ is the set of all integers that differ from $a$ by a multiple of $n/d$.
*Exemple:* $n=8,d=4 \Rightarrow f([3]+G)=[3]_2=[1]_2 \in \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} $

2-
Now let's check that the morphism property is respected.
$f(a+G+b+G)=f(a+b+G)=[a+b]_{\frac{n}{d}}=[a]_{\frac{n}{d}}+[b]_{\frac{n}{d}}=f(a+G)+f(b+G)$
(Edited after the remark of @otr)->For $f$ to be well-defined, it must map equivalent cosets to the same element. If $a + G = b + G$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) / G$, then $a - b \in G$. Since $G$ consists of multiples of $n/d$, $a \equiv b \mod (n/d)$. Hence, $f$ is well-defined. See further explanation in part "3-" on injectivity. <-

3-
*Surjectivity:* by definition of $f$ every element in $\mathbb{Z}/(n/d) \mathbb{Z}$ as a pre image in $  (\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} ) / G $. For exemple $ \forall [a] \in \mathbb{Z}/(n/d) \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow $ we have $a+G$ that gives $f(a+G)=[a]_{\frac{n}{d}} $
*Injectivity:*  By definition if $f(a+G)=f(b+G) \Rightarrow [a]_{\frac{n}{d}}=[b]_{\frac{n}{d}}$ so there $a$ and $b$ have the same euclidian rest after being divised by $n/d \Rightarrow a= \alpha \cdot \frac{n}{d}+r , b = \beta \cdot \frac{n}{d}+r \Rightarrow a-b = (\alpha - \beta) \cdot \frac{n}{d} \in G$ as all the element of $G$ are of the form: $k \cdot \frac{n}{d}$.
And because $a+G=b+G$ iff $a-b \in G$ we get that $a+G=b+G$.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that $card((\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G) = n/d$ is definitely helpful. What would also be helpful is showing that the quotient of any cyclic group is also cyclic (i.e. $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G$ is cyclic). Now, what are some good candidates $a+G \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G$ that would generate this entire quotient group?

Comment: thk or your answer but thi is exactly where i am stuck!

Comment: I ve written an swer I will be happy to have your review on it.

Comment: Thk for your answer. I ve edited my answer but before there were all ready an explanation of the your point "(2)" in my "3-" and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834543/simple-question-on-a-sub-group-g-of-mathbbz-n-mathbbz

Comment: Sorry, your claim about the elements of $G$ being multiples of $\frac{n}{d}$ at the end is not true, I think. Take $n = 8$ and $G = 2\mathbb{Z} / 8\mathbb{Z}$ (multiples of 2 modulo 8). Then $(\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})/G$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, meaning that $\frac{n}{d} = 4$.

Comment: can you edit your message by putting the "$" in the right place so I can understand it please ?

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: But in those case we have that the number of element in $G$ is infinite! And the exercice told us that it is finite with cardinal $d$? Am I right. Btw if you can details more on how will looks like the group $ ( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/G$ with your $G=2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})$ it will be great as I try to exercise myself understanding such concept

Comment: it's ok thk you for your help.

Comment: In this example, $G = 2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ is actually not infinite. It's just the numbers $\{0,2,4,6\}$ with the group operation being addition modulo $8$. For example, $4+6 \equiv 10 \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834543/simple-question-on-a-sub-group-g-of-mathbbz-n-mathbbz I ve tried to understand how looks like $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}  ) /G$ any precision will be appreciated!

Comment: ok so I ve well understood and your scripture confuse me a little bit. In such a case we have that $G$ is a cyclic group generated by $8/4=n/d=k=2$. So all the element of $G$ are of the form $ 2l=(n/d)l=kl$ no ?

Comment: I don't understand why my prove for injectivity in part "-3" is not correct?

Comment: Ah sorry, I retract what I said. $G$ is indeed multiples of $\frac{n}{d}$ modulo $n$.

Comment: it's ok thank a lot for your remark that helps me sharping my understanding.

Comment: It's not that it's incorrect. It just has a gap in its proof. How do you know that $G$ consists of the multiples of $\frac{n}{d}$ modulo $n$?

Comment: Here a justification https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834543/simple-question-on-a-sub-group-g-of-mathbbz-n-mathbbz (look at part "1- undestanding $G$")

Comment: Ah, great! Then the proof looks complete to me.

Comment: thk a lot for your comment!